# Use different background images for different images in a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, velo

I have a div element with almost 30 images and I want every image to have a separate background. I want my slider with these images to display watermarked image with zero opacity and on front and at back I can add original images. Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried to do it using nth-child as every image have same class.

As it is a code which is part of a slider so basically I want it to work like all the images on the front to be transparent and the background images to be displayed when slider moves.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 
    col-sm-12" style="   
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;" style=" overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="rotation" style="position: relative; width: 100%;" style=" overflow: hidden;">
      <img class="magnifiedImg" src="img_girl.jpg" style="display: 
    block; width: 100%; height:auto !important; ; ">
```

Comment: You're obviously using Bootstrap, so that should be tagged (by version). Also, don't use inline styles. Most of what you've written can be replaced with Bootstrap classes anyway, and custom classes are much better than junked up HTML. And you have multiple style attributes on several elements, which is invalid. Some of that isn't even in effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this.  You can have an extra `div` set to `position: absolute;` inside your "`.row`" container.   Just make sure that `.row` has `position: relative;` and that you're `.watermark` is `position: absolute; width 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;`

```css
.row {
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.watermark {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .9;
  /* set opacity to 0 to see it without the watermark. */
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.fake-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.fake-image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="watermark">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/?text=Water+Mark" />
 </div>
 <div class="fake-image">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/31343C?text=Image" />
 </div>
 <!-- Image divs go here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it only helped to resolve image hiding but i want to add watermark images that user can download and is transparent over real image.

Comment: Just updated it to explicitly do what you're looking for.  The watermark div, is sitting on top of the images container.    All you have to do is make sure that you use a .png with no background on the water mark div.

Comment: I've you're looking to mix 2 images on the FE, there's no easy way to do that.  You'll need to use something like Lightroom, or an other photo processing app to apply the water marks to the images.